# azure service bus & dynamics crm integration

Tags: java, azure, dynamics-crm

I am currently working on a POC where I am draining messages from an azure queue -  that is populated through a dynamics CRM plugin during DB CRUD operations.The queue drain operation using a java client fails with the message :

```
<Error>
<Code>500</Code>
<Detail>
The service was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101. TrackingId:add85f1a-a249-4e69-b284-ad879cd29968_G27, SystemTracker:scsqueue1-ns:Queue:scsqueue1, Timestamp:7/6/2016 7:21:49 PM
</Detail>
</Error>
```

The java client can be found here :
https://github.com/sharpcodes/scs-bus-demo

However using a C# client works

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the obvious issue in your code on GitHub. However, per my experience, I suggest that you can try to use the tool [`Fiddler`](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for debugging the rest request from your code, because the Azure Service Bus SDK for Java is wrapped the REST APIs, such as [`Receive and Delete Message (Destructive Read)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780770.aspx) for draining messages.

Meanwhile, there are three ways below in Java for draining messages via the operation `Receive and Delete Message` on Azure.

1. Using Azure Service Bus SDK for Java, please refer to the section [`Receive messages from a queue`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues/#receive-messages-from-a-queue) of the tutorial "How to use Service Bus queues" to do with default mode `ReceiveAndDelete`.
2. Using Azure Service Bus REST API for Java with http client, please refer to the section [`Receive and delete a message from the queue`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-brokered-tutorial-rest/#receive-and-delete-a-message-from-the-queue) of the tutorial "Service Bus brokered messaging REST tutorial".
3. Using JMS API with AMQP 1.0 in Java, please refer to the section [`Coding Java applications`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp/#coding-java-applications) of the tutorial "How to use the Java Message Service (JMS) API with Service Bus and AMQP 1.0" to see the function `SimpleSenderReceiver()`.

Comment: Thanks peter.. The JMS API seems to work fine. The SDK based approach seems to be failing across multiple platforms..https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/issues/823
Seems like the urls are not properly escaped in the messages created by the OOB dynamics plugin..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to peter for guiding on this..

Looks like there is an issue with the dynamics crm-azure bus plugin that prevents java/node-js clients from draining the queue using SDKs or RestFul calls.

Using  JMS client seems to do the trick. Another way would be to have a C# middleware that could be wrapped by Java/Node.

Here is the reference to the issue : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/issues/823

Answer (score 0):

The issue is closed now as a fix had to be made by Azure Java SDK team to escape characters correctly..